# Chinese character are written as question marks in the SQL database

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

I am  using `ADO.net` to write a string to a field in a table of Microsoft SQL Server 2005 database.
I am using `SqlBulkCopy::WriteToServer` api to write to SQL database.
The data type of the column in Sql database table is of type `varchar2`. 
If I change the datatype to nvarchar the chinese characters are written properly. But I think it should work with data type `varchar2` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `VARCHAR2` data type in SQL Server - you must use `NVARCHAR`.

`VARCHAR2` exists in Oracle (and possibly other database platforms).

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention that `Varchar2` doesnot exist in SQL and youhave to use `NVARCHAR`.

By the way your problem is not belong to it, it is because of SQL Collasion, when You (or admin) were installing the SQL Server, you set Chinese as the collasion. so when SQL cannot find an equevalent for a character, then replace it with a chinese character.